# What tool to simulate rfid events on windows (python-win32 compatible?)

Tags: python, winapi, pyqt, nfc, rfid

I'm building a medical application that should respond to a RFID card scan (and pop up some information). I'm using PyQT to build this, btw.

Could someone tell me what tool to use to simulate rfid scans on the machine ? I'm a little noob to this, but I'm assuming I'll use a USB based reader and I should be able to somehow hook to the reader to get some data.

Help...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is pretty much no way we can know how a particular rfid reader will work. Your best  would just be to assume that it will fire off events somehow, and implement a fake rfid reader that sends off a string of data (that you expect to get from an rfid chip) when you want. Once you get an rfid reader, you can then wrap whatever library you have been provided to access it (or write your own) so that it matches the format/communications protocol you made up for your fake one.

But the far simpler solution is to just get yourself an rfid reader and find out experimentally...